# VB6's equivalent code in C#

Tags: c#, vb6

This is a sample code which I have to convert in C#. As this code was written long ago and I don't have deep idea about VB, it will be really helpful if a C# version is given.

The code:

```vb
ChDir ("c:\folder")
a = Shell("c:\folder\some.exe C /LINK ", 1)        
Sleep 6000   'Implements a 1 second delay
sParameters = "Something"
a = ExecCmd(sParameters)
```

I have searched on MSDN and saw what Shell does, but I am still confused. 
Please help me.

Comment: Please remove the tag vb.net since the question is about vb which is very different to vb.net!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search about

```
Process.Start("c:\folder\some.ex");
```

If your app needs arguments :

```
ProcessStartInfo si= new processStartInfo();
si.fileName="c:\folder\some.exe";
si.CreateNoWindow = false;
si.UseShellExecute = false;

si.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
si.arguments="arguments here";
try
    {
        // Start the process with the info we specified.
        // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(si))
        {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Log error.
    }
```

Comment: I know about the Process.Start, but I am confused about the "C /LINK" part in Shell function, is it actually a parameter or something else?

Comment: i think it's a parameter

Comment: Okay, now this is making sense. If I got this correct I think, this runs some.exe with parameter and after that ExecCmd runs cmd.exe with another parameter.